# Angular 8 - Azure Server Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: angular, azure, build, azure-pipelines

I made a few changes in the **Azure pipeline** and the system started getting the following error.
It does not give any error in the local environment, it works smoothly during Azure build, but after publishing, the system gives a white screen and does not work.

> error detail

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at main.18f4494f2c11857ad225.js:2:1389490)
```

[image]

> index.html is as follows. Angular build adds scripts to the script
> section. No error appears

[image]

> tsconfig.json confugiration detail.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*", "tests/**/*" ]
}
```

> Angular.json production configurations detail.

```
{
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "budgets": [
      {
        "type": "initial",
        "maximumWarning": "5mb",
        "maximumError": "10mb"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> Pipeline setting confugiration.
> [image]

> Azure pipeline progress
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing the `index.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href=".">
```

You may specify the path to the folder containing your index.html:

```
<base href="/path/to/index-folder">
```

2. If the `main.bundle.js` wasn't present. The problem can be resolved by copying the file once again to the `dist` folder.

Comment: I changed the base href as you said before but I still got the same error.